# The asterisk is not a character constant?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

`foo.cpp`:

```
#define ID A
#if ID == A
#warning "hello, world"
#endif
```

Compilation with `g++ -c foo.cpp` works fine: (g++ v8.2.0)

```
foo.cpp:3:2: warning: #warning "hello, world" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "hello, world"
  ^~~~~~~
```

Now, if I replace `#define ID A` with `#define *`, then I get:

```
foo.cpp:1:12: error: operator '*' has no left operand
 #define ID *
            ^
foo.cpp:2:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ID’
 #if ID == A
     ^~
```

*What is so special about `*`? Why does it fail in the `#if` expression?*

Comment: Well `*` is an operator, and can't be part of an identifier since only `[A-Za-z0-9_]` are allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things of note in your post. The first, is that it doesn't work as you think. This will [produce the warning too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/426dd5f48426a3bc)

```
#define ID B
#if ID == A
#warning "hello, world"
#endif
```

The reason is that in the context of `#if` the preprocessing tokens `ID` and `A` are taken as macros and are expanded. Since `A` is not defined, it is "expanded" to 0. So is `ID` via the expansion `ID` -> `B` -> `0`. So the condition is true here as well.

This also answers why `*` causes an error. It cannot be expanded further (on account of not being a valid identifier), and therefore you get the comparison `* == 0`, which is nonsense.

Since your title implies you seek to compare against a character constant, the way to do that would be to define `ID` to expand *into the token sequence* of a character constant.

```
#define ID 'A'
#if ID == 'A'
```

It should now work as expected. As will `#define ID '*'`

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I was assuming that in the C++ preprocessor, plain single letter identifiers act as character constants. *Maybe you can add why `*` cannot be expanded further?* (I presume, because it is not a valid identifier.) Unfortunately, switching from `A` to `'A'` creates other issues, since I would like to use `#A` as part of assembling an ID specific include file name.

Comment: @feklee - Added that tidbit to my answer. Since you are using GCC you could try giving its extensions a look. IIRC `#$` OR `#@` produces a character, same as the standaed `#` produces a string literal.

Comment: `#@` is [MSVC preprocessor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/91tt6dfs(v=vs.110)). It’s called the *charizing operator*, and there seems to be no equivalent for GCC.

Answer (score 1):

`#if` [does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional) not what you think it is doing.

In your first example, it tries to evaluate `0 == 0`, which is a valid expression with a value of `true`.

In your second example, it tries to evaluate `* == 0`, which is not a valid expression.